What's wrong with this below C code for quick sort?
This is my C code for the Quick sort algorithm, I'm facing errors if I give input for n above a certain limit (mostly above 40). It just stops midway.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int t;
    t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

int partition(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int i, j, pivot, t;
    pivot = a[low];
    i = low;
    j = high;

    while (i < j) {
        while (a[i] < pivot) 
            i = i + 1;

        while (a[j] > pivot)
            j = j - 1;

        if (i < j) {
           swap(&a[i], &a[j]);
        }
    }

    swap(&pivot, &a[j]);
    return j;
}

void quicksort(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high) {
        int p = partition(a, low, high);
        quicksort(a, low, p - 1);
        quicksort(a, p + 1, high);
    }
}

void main()
{
    int n, a[5000];
    clock_t s, e;
    printf("Enter number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n); 
    printf("Before sorting:");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % 100; 
        printf("%d  ", a[i]);
    }
    s = clock();
    quicksort(a, 0, n - 1);
    e = clock();
    double time_taken = (double)(e - s) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time taken to sort %d elements: %f seconds\n", n, time_taken);
    printf("After sorting:");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        printf("%d\t", a[i]);
}

I can't figure out why isn't this working for inputs above 40. Please can anyone solve this.
The errors I face are,
Enter number of elements: 50

Before sorting:

It would stop right there.

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems? and How to debug small programs

Your code for partition enters an infinite loop in some circumstances in which there are two elements with the same value. You need to allow for some elements to be equal to the pivot.

okay, got it @EricPostpischil

Aside: If you picked up void main() from a book or online resource, you may wish to look for a better one.

Consider what happens in partition when there is another element with the same value as pivot. If j reaches this element while i still equals low, so it indicates a[i], which is the pivot element, then:

a[i] < pivot is false, so i is not incremented.
a[j] > pivot is false, so j is not decremented.
i<j is true, so swap(&a[i],&a[j]) is executed, but this has no effect because a[i] and a[j] are equal.

Therefore the loop continues forever.
To fix this, you must allow for elements that equal the pivot. Changing a[j] > pivot to a[j] >= pivot and/or a[i] < pivot to a[i] <= pivot may suffice, although I have not evaluated these thoroughly.

This results in a new error,
the output is,
Enter number of elements: 5
Before sorting:41       467     334     500     169
Time taken to sort 5 elements: 0.000002 seconds
After sorting:41        467     467     467     500

@SVenkateshwaran: Have you considered debugging your program, particularly by tracing its execution in a debugger or via inserting numerous printf statements to display what it is doing, so that you can follow execution step-by-step and see where it is doing something you do not want it to do?

Thts wht im trying now, @EricPostpischil

The error was, trying to swap pivot and a[j] ,
It's working fine, when we swap a[low] and a[j]
